# How to get rid of the com_error when running MS-word macro with python?

Tags: python, ms-word, macros, win32com

I'm trying to run a MS-word VBA macro with python, but I keep getting an error.

```
import win32com.client as win32

WrdApp = win32.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")

#Call current file
WrdDoc = WrdApp.ActiveDocument

#Insert Caption
WrdApp.Selection.InsertCaption(Label='number')
#^This line gives the error
```

Error Message

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Command failed', 'wdmain11.chm', 36966, -2146824090), None)
```

Anyone familiar with Python and MS-word Macro can tell me why I got this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use other labels than 'Equation', 'Figure', 'Table' or WdCaptionLabelID in Label, you must to **define new one** (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertcaption, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.captionlabels):

```
import win32com.client as win32

WrdApp = win32.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")

# Call current file
WrdDoc = WrdApp.ActiveDocument

cLabel = "number"
# define new label
WrdApp.CaptionLabels.Add(Name=cLabel)
# Insert Caption
WrdApp.Selection.InsertCaption(Label=cLabel)
# no error
```